# NullPointerException in custom adapter getView while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I'm building an SMS app and on the activity which shows the list of SMS between the user and his conversation's partner i was trying to have a `ListView` with 2 different layouts, which will represent incoming and outgoing SMSs.

everything worked great until i'm trying to work with the 2 layouts.
i can see the list of SMS correctly with the 2 different layout for incoming\outgoing as i need. but when i scroll the list then i get an NullPointerException.

this is my Adapter:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sms> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(ExistingConversation.this, R.layout.item_conversation_incoming, smsList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return smsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // find the Sms to work with
        Sms currentSms = smsList.get(position);

        // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            if (currentSms.getIncomingOutgoing().equals("in")){// inflate the list for an incoming message
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_conversation_incoming, parent, false);
            }
            else{ // inflate the list for an outgoing message
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_conversation_outgoing, parent, false);
            }
        }

        // Fill the view:
        if (currentSms.getIncomingOutgoing().equals("in")){ //for incoming
            // Content:
            TextView contentView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_content_incoming);
            contentView.setText(currentSms.getContent());

            // time:
            TextView timeView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_time_incoming);
            timeView.setText(new Date(currentSms.getDate()).toString().substring(0, 19));
        }
        else{//for outgoing
            // Content:
            TextView contentView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_content_outgoing);
            contentView.setText(currentSms.getContent());

            // time:
            TextView timeView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_time_outgoing);
            timeView.setText(new Date(currentSms.getDate()).toString().substring(0, 19));

        }
        return itemView;
    }
}
}
```

these are my 2 layouts:
incoming:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_container_incoming"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_incoming"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon_incoming"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/social_person2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_content_incoming"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="Here Goes The Content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_time_incoming"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the outgoing 1 is the all the same except the places where it is writen "incoming" (which is obviously wrtien  `outgoing` , and in the `RelativeLayout`'s attribute of padding (instaed of Right padding it is Left padding...)

in addition i will post here my logCat stack trace - it might help in finding a solution to my annoying problem:

```
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at com.example.smser.ExistingConversation$MyListAdapter.getView(ExistingConversation.java:356)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2452)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1776)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:712)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:651)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5711)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3422)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4087)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7380)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2464)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2470)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2212)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2470)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2212)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2470)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2212)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2470)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2212)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow. java:2151)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1480)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2099)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7565)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3427)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3359)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4468)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4446)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4550)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4518)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4569)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-11 20:18:38.707: E/AndroidRuntime(23441):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So i got this deadline for tomorrow and i got to find a **fast solution** (meaning, at the moment, i less care about efficiency - i will take care about it later on).

Please if you can help me it will be great! for any clarification or question feel free to post a comment i'll will do my best to explain even farther...

thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
so i found out that for some reason, if i'm commenting the following `if` it works:

```
  //if (itemView == null) {
        if (currentSms.getIncomingOutgoing().equals("in")){// inflate the list for an incoming message
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_conversation_incoming, parent, false);
        }
        else{ // inflate the list for an outgoing message
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_conversation_outgoing, parent, false);
        }
    //}
```

but something tell me that wrong... I'm still  interesting in hearing some other point of view about it... 
thanks

**EDIT:**

the line that causing the execption is that one:

```
                contentView.setText(currentSms.getContent());
```

Comment: On line 356 you have something that's `null`.  There's not really any mysteries involved with null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize `View`s such as `contentView`, `timeView` in the first `if..else` where you check whether `itemView` is `null` or not.

Comment: i'm trying that... 1 minute please..

Comment: ok! you are right! i change the code so it will be less "pretty" but i've putted all the initializition along with the assignments and its worked...

should i update my question with the working code for other to learn from?

Comment: @goldengil that would be nice, I think. And you might want to use `ViewHolder` for performance, it's just an inner class that holds `View`s so you don't need to initialize them each time a row is created. Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder

Comment: thank you! in the mean time i got a different problem - the order of the items in the list is getting messed up while scrolling. I've updated my code to use `VieHolder` pattern and still nothing. maybe you got an idea? still havent found the solution for that :/

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to initialize `currentSms` before using it? If not, please indicate which one is the error line

Comment: i am initializing it at the begining of `getView`
the line that popping the exception is:   contentView.setText(currentSms.getContent());   i will update in question